# Extract Data from pcap file

Tags: linux, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

Is there any way to extract this data (red box on below image) and save it in a text file in Linux command line? I tried searching on web but couldn't get anything related to my issue. I want to drop these packets on Iptables using their HEX.

[image: pcap file]

Comment: I would use  a scripting language like Python. There are Python libraries for reading pcap files and thus filtering and extracting data should be not that complex.

Comment: @Robert there are no tools for doing this over commandline without any scripting lang?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in using Python and would prefer to use a CLI command, [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) is what you're looking for. It is the official Wireshark tool for interfacing with packet captures in a non-GUI environment.

[tshark.dev](https://tshark.dev/) has some great resources that would assist you in getting the specific information you are interested in. It will be difficult for me to select what you're looking for without the PCAP, but something like this should work for you:

```shell
tshark -n -T fields -e data
```